# Check if a directory-tree can be deleted without actually starting to delete it

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

In my program I need to be able to delete the directory with the old output. But some files inside it might be locked. In this case, I want to warn the user that he needs to close the applications that lock them before the program can proceed, with a Retry/Cancel dialog, and if the user clicks Cancel, I want the directory to stay intact.

So, can anyone tell me of a way to check if an entire directory tree can be deleted (no locked files in any subdirectories), without modifying its contents - something like a dry-run.

Comment: methinks this would be highly OS-dependent. so what OS?

Comment: Not sure, and as @SchighSchagh says, OS-dependent.  Maybe you could try temporarily renaming the root folder - perhaps this operation would be refused if it made open files inaccessible? You could copy the whole folder into a temp backup, but this could take a long time :(

Comment: @SchighSchagh Oops, I didn't think to add Windows, I thought the winapi (as in Windows' API) is enough, sorry :)

Comment: Still some file can get locked after your check and before you start deleting.

Comment: Yes, [winapi] should be enough. This is one tag with a very clear and distinct description in its wiki, so nobody could get confused!

Comment: Note that this can *never* be done reliably. If nothing else, then a file may become locked after you make that check. You can do your best to *try* to find problems to warn the user about, but you can never guarantee that "if the dry-run succeeded, then the real thing will work too"

Comment: While you are correct in theory, in practice, if the dry run succeeds, I would proceed to delete it immediately. The dialog is displayed only if it fails. So the window of opportunity for this problem is a few milliseconds.

Comment: What you've just described is a situation we call a "race condition". This is not just a theoretical problem, it's an actual one. There is absolutely nothing that prevents another process from doing something to block deletion *in between* the time you check if it will work and the time you actually issue the command to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could try and rename the parent directory, in Windows at least you would get an error saying it is not possible if a file in a subfolder is locked. If rename succeeds it should be safe to delete and prevents others of accessing the tree before you delete it.

Comment: Heh!  I had same thought, though I would have to try it.

Comment: Yes, this is probably the safest bet since it should be very fast (a single system call), and it would preclude most cases of files becoming locked after you start deleting. But double check that rename of a directory fails when some file(s) in that dir (or subdir thereof) are open.

Answer (score 1):

You can call [_access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w06ktdy%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) function on each file in directory-tree. But still someone can lock a file after it was checked.

Comment: I tried that but _access actually doesn't fail even if the file is locked.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Restart Manager will tell you if any files are in use and offer to shut them down. Nothing will protect against the race condition of something locking them after your check though.